# Linux stat(2) call gives non-existing device ID

Tags: c, linux, std, glibc, proc

My test program is calling [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) to obtain a device the file resides on.

`stat.c`  (built with `cc stat.c -o stat`)

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/sysmacros.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char *path = "/home/smoku/test.txt";
    unsigned int maj, min;
    struct stat sb;
    if (stat(path, &sb) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error getting stat for '%s': %d %s\n", path, errno, strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    maj = major(sb.st_dev);
    min = minor(sb.st_dev);
    fprintf(stderr, "Found '%s' => %u:%u\n", path, maj, min);
    return 0;
}
```

Got `0:44`

```
$ ls -l /home/smoku/test.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 smoku smoku 306 08-30 09:33 /home/smoku/test.txt

$ ./stat
Found '/home/smoku/test.txt' => 0:44

$ /usr/bin/stat -c "%d" /home/smoku/test.txt
44
```

But... there is no such device in my system and `/home` is `0:35`

```
$ grep /home /proc/self/mountinfo
75 59 0:35 /home /home rw,relatime shared:30 - btrfs /dev/bcache0 rw,ssd,space_cache,subvolid=258,subvol=/home
```

Why do I get a device ID that does not exist in my system?

Comment: Do you check what `stat` returns? It doesn't return with a failure (`-1`)?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg ...it most probably does...

Comment: Yes I did. This is just excerpt from the real program.

Comment: Then please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that you can show us. It's really impossible to tell with that (non-working) code to say anything.

Comment: Sure. I fixed the code to be full.

Comment: `stat -c "%t:%T" /home/smoku/test.txt` in a terminal window should do the same thing with a *proven to be working* program and allow you to verify your output

Comment: @tofro this gives `0:0`

Comment: @tofro `stat -c "%d" /home/smoku/test.txt` gives `44`

Comment: @tofro `man 1 stat` says that `t` and `T` are "for character/block device special files"

Comment: yes you are right - I was somehow assuming you look for the type of device rather than the id - so 44 is proven to exist

Comment: Using `%lu` with `dev_t` is not specified to be correct.  Instead use `fprintf(stderr, "Will look for %d => %u:%u\n", (long) sb.st_dev, maj, min);` or `fprintf(stderr, "Will look for %jd => %u:%u\n", (intmax_t) sb.st_dev, maj, min);`

Comment: @chux on my system `dev_t` is `unsigned long`, and casting it didn't change the outcome

Comment: @chux also, no matter the printing format, after major()/minor() i should get proper `unsigned:unsigned` pair, which gave me still `0:44`

Comment: Good that you cast the value before printing as that eliminates one source of potential UB.  That fact that you type some combination that _should_ work is not as strong as code that is _specified_ to work.  IAC, we can move forward from this.

Comment: @chux in fact it introduces the potential issue, as it may be silently loosing part of the value if improperly cast. I will edit the code to remove this printing, as it obviously does not help

Comment: Per `man 2 stat`, `st_dev` describes the device _on which this file resides_, in your case, obviously `/dev/bcache0`.

Comment: @user58697 `/dev/bcache0` is `252:0` ->  `brw-rw---- 1 root disk 252, 0 09-13 20:53 /dev/bcache0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stat(2)` in `fs/stat.c` uses `inode->i_sb->s_dev` to fill `stat.st_dev`

`/proc/self/mountinfo` in `fs/proc_namespace.c` uses `mnt->mnt_sb->s_dev`

Apparently `struct inode`.`i_sb` superblock may be different to `struct vfsmount`.`mnt_sb` superblock in case of mount of *btrfs subvolume*.

This is an issue inherent to btrfs implementation, which *"requires non-trivial changes in the VFS layer"* to fix: https://mail-archive.com/linux-btrfs@vger.kernel.org/msg57667.html

Comment: "*kernel bug*" -- Perhaps it is, but if it were me, I wouldn't be relying particularly much on device numbers emitted by such filesystems as btrfs that have such a complete abstraction between physical devices and the VFS layer. I wouldn't be surprised if ZFS had similar effects.